# Nginx Sub-Domain+Folder to Domain+URI Redirect

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect old sub-domain with folder to new domain without that old folder but including the uri. Perhaps there is a way to remove "/tv/" part on new redirected url.

OLD URL:

```
http://demo.domain.com/tv/page1/id1
```

NEW URL (WANTED):

```
http://http://domain.com/page1/id1
```

Now this rule is what I have so far and it kind of works:

```
server {
  listen ip:port;
  server_name demo.domain.com;
  return 301 http://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

This redirects to:

```
http://domain.com/tv/page1/id1
```

and I need to remove that "tv" part from url, and have it redirect to:

```
http://domain.com/page1/id1
```

But at same time I need to have 301 redirect that is good for SEO.

If you have any ideas, please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I got it =) But if anyone knows any other and perhaps better way, please share =)

```
server {
  listen ip:80;
  server_name demo.domain.com;
  rewrite ^/tv(.*) http://domain.com$1 permanent; break;
}
```